# how to use system's environnement variables in sql script

Tags: sql, linux, psql

i want to use several linux environment variables inside a sql script that i run with this command :

```
psql -h XXX -p 5432 -U XXX -d XXX -f ./script.sql
```

the content of the script is a succession of this line, but the referencing doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't replace the value, even though env variables exist

```
alter user airflow with password '$PASSWORD';
```

do you have a way ?

I tried to run a script with references to linux environment variables, but it interprets it as a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsubst` to substitute environment variables :

```
psql -h XXX -p 5432 -U XXX -d XXX -f <(envsubst < ./script.sql)
```